# Discord bot opus with python

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to develop a discord music bot. Below is a simplified version of my actual code, though both yield the same error.

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUIILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        if not discord.opus.is_loaded():
            discord.opus.load_opus("opus")

    async def on_message(self,message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

client = MyClient()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I get the following error:

```
Logged on as music-player#2653!
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/general3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot_v2.py", line 13, in on_ready
    discord.opus.load_opus("opus")
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/general3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/opus.py", line 156, in load_opus
    _lib = libopus_loader(name)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/general3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/opus.py", line 83, in libopus_loader
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(name)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: opus: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have opuslib and ffmpeg installed.

```
ffmpeg-python==0.2.0
opuslib==3.0.1
```

The possible solutions I came across, that do not work was to change `discord.opus.load_opus()` to `discord.opus.load_opus("opus")`, Installing `ffmpeg-python` and `opuslib`. I am using version 1.0.1 of discord.py

Is there anything I am missing?